# iOS Development: Is there ever a time when it's appropriate for an app to kill itself?

Tags: ios, iphone, kill

I've been developing iOS apps for enterprise use for several years now. It was an adjustment from having spent many (!) years developing desktop apps. One of the first things I learned very early on was that it is frowned upon for an app to kill itself. The posters in the Apple dev forum were downright hostile about it, which is a reason I never go there anymore.

Now I have an app that has very critical functions, and it requires that the user accept the terms and conditions before using the app, and that the app will not function if the terms have not been accepted. The choice is there to accept or to decline, but it seems like the best thing to do when the user actively declines is to kill the app entirely.

My question is, under those circumstances, would there be anything wrong with that? Will I be damned to developers hell for eternity?

Comment: No, don't do that. There is always a better way to do what you think you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why kill an app on a declying? I would rather just leave a user at the same screen with no actions before he puts acceptance checkbox, disabling all buttons

Comment: I used a variation of your suggestion: I just placed a label that tells the user to close the app manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the interaction here.

Instead of `accept (and use the app)` or `decline (and never be able to use the app)` change it to `accept (and use the app)` or nothing.

If the user does not accept then they cannot use the app. They do not have to decline anything. Absence of acceptance is all you need.

If they don't accept then don't do anything. They can always come back later and accept and start using the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the app kill itself, Apple won't let you post it on the App Store.

You should adjust your User Experience to the case of the user declining the terms and conditions.

For example, show a screen saying that the app can't be used unless terms are accepted, with a button saying "Take me back" that takes the user back to the terms screen.

Comment: Good advice. To be clear, this is an Enterprise app. It would not be going through the App Store.

Comment: @BillNorman whether the app is an enterprise app or distributed through the App Store it is still important to create a good user experience for the user. A lot of the guidelines from Apple are there to do just that :)